# Drawing multiple graphs with subplot when y-axis takes two values

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I wanna draw 5 graphs with subplots where is each graph, y-axis should show 2 values (multiple y axes). I am using the following code, but I have some difficulties. I don't know how to add a title for each graph, how to add a general legend for all graphs, how to force that x-axis for each graph increase with step 1 and y-axis with step 0.5.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(3,2,figsize=(10,10))
ax2 = np.array([a.twinx() for a in ax1.ravel()]).reshape(ax1.shape)

x = np.arange(0,16)
curve1 = ax1[0,0].plot(x, optimal_policy[1,:-1,0], label='Optimal p', color='r',marker='o',linestyle='--')
curve2 = ax2[0,0].plot(x, optimal_policy[1,:-1,1], label='Optimal b', color='b',marker='v',linestyle='-.')
ax2[0,0].set_ylabel('b') 
ax1[0,0].set_ylabel('p') 
ax1[0,0].set_ylim(0,4)
ax2[0,0].set_ylim(0,4)

fig.legend(loc='upper right',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.5))

plt.title('Inventory =1')
plt.xlabel('Time')
ax1[0,0].set_xlabel('Time')
```

`x` and `optimal_policy[1,:-1,0]` are vectors with size 16. This is just one of the graph and it is ok to replicate this graph for other subplots.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right this will resolve your problem. You can adjust your axis range with `min` and `max` of your `x,y` arrays.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0,16)
y1 =  np.random.rand(16,1)*5
y2 =  np.random.rand(16,1)*4

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=False, figsize=(10,10))

ax12 = ax1.twinx() 
l, = ax1.plot(x,y1,'g',label='Optimal p')
l2, = ax12.plot(x,y2,'b',label='Optimal b')


ax22 = ax2.twinx() 
l3, = ax2.plot(x,y1,'g',label='Optimal p')
l4, = ax22.plot(x,y2,'b',label='Optimal b')

ax1.title.set_text('First Plot')
ax2.title.set_text('Second Plot')

ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="g")
ax12.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="b")
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="g")
ax22.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="b")    

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0,16,1))
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(0,16,1))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(10)+0.5)
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(10)+0.5)

plt.legend( handles=[l, l2, l3, l4],loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=[0, 1],
           ncol=2, shadow=True, title="Legend", fancybox=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to add two y axes. The left y-axis is based on p and the right y-axis is based on b. I think this code does not show two axes.

Comment: Ok, no problem I will edit the code. I hope this will be useful :)